# linear ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the exact solution of the system: 
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\operatorname{d}y}{\operatorname{d}t} &= -15y- 25z \\
\frac{\operatorname{d}z}{\operatorname{d}t} &= -47y-85z 
\end{align}
$$

either by the writing the equations in matrix form as $\frac{\operatorname{d}x}{\operatorname{d}t} =Ax$ where $x=\pmatrix{y\\ z}$ and diagonalising the matrix $A$, or otherwise.

Comment: Hi randy, welcome to Math SE.  In general, it is considered good practice when asking what seems to be a homework question to include details of what work/methods you have already used in attempting to arrive at a solution. This shows that you have put effort into solving the problem, and allows other users to provide better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the method; I think it is sufficient for you to work from here and find the solution for yourself.

Find the eigenvalues of your matrix $A$ by solving $\text{det}(A-\lambda I)=0$, and then find the corresponding eigenvectors.  As in the 2nd order single system case, you end up with a solution
$$\mathbf{x}=c_1e^{\lambda_1t}\mathbf{a_1}+c_2e^{\lambda_2t}\mathbf{a_2}$$
where $\mathbf{a_i}$ is the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_i$

Comment: thanks @Christopher Ernst, what is c1 and c2?

Comment: $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary constants.  Both $e^{\lambda_1}\mathbf{a_1}$ and $e^{\lambda_2}\mathbf{a_2}$ are solutions themselves of the system.  But linearity allows all linear combinations of these two vectors to also be solutions, so $c_1$ and $c_2$ are simple constants.

Comment: once i find the value of a1 and a2 along with λ1 and λ2. Then is it general solution same as exact solution?

Comment: an exact solution comes when you are given an initial value problem.  As an example, if your initial value problem is $\mathbf{x}(0)= (0  0)^T$, then you can plug those values into the general solution and solve the system for the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: x = c1 (1  -0.5596) e^(-50+20√6)t + c2(1  3.3596) e^(-50-20√6)t. This is what i have got.And inital condition is given by x=(y,z) y(0)=2, z(0)=5

Comment: i got c1=0.4386 and c2=1.5613

Comment: For the exact solution i got                                                         y= 0.4386 e^(-50+20√6)t + 1.5613  e^(-50-20√6)t.                              z= -0.2455 e^(-50+20√6)t + 5.2453 e^(-50-20√6)t                         does this sound correct?

Comment: Let me try it myself...

Comment: i want to plot the graph y_n against the exact solution and z_n against the exact solution. can someone help me to get Matmab code for the numerical solution of y_n and z_n.

Comment: Alrite.Thanks for your help.

Comment: I got different eigenvectors.  I used Maple, and using the linear algebra package plugged A into both the eigenvector and eigenvalue function and the eigenvalues you got are right, but the eigenvectors i got are $\left(\frac{-35}{47}-\frac{20\sqrt{6}}{47},1\right)^T$ and $\left(\frac{-35}{47}+\frac{20\sqrt{6}}{47},1\right)^T$.  So solving, $c_1=-.245469...,c_2=5.245469...$.

Answer (score 1):

Just provide "otherwise". Solve $\displaystyle z=-\frac{y'+15y}{25}$ from the first equation and then substitute into the second equation. One obtains
a second order linear homogeneous ode $$y''+ay'+by=0$$
There are lots of [methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Summary_of_exact_solutions) to solve this such as Frobenius' method, Laplacian transformation method, method of annihilator, etc. Next substitute $y',y$ back into the first equation to get $z$. These methods may sometimes be faster than diagonalizing the matrix.